# Number of partitions in a given size, with or without a specific element in one of the partitions

Tags: combinatorics

If we have no restrictions, 6 elements can be partitioned in groups of 2 in
$$
\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{3!}
$$
number of ways. But if we have the restriction that a certain element must belong to a given group, the number of partitions become
$$
\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{2!}
$$

that is, we choose just *one* element of five to this group with the given element.

In the case with no restrictions, we divide by $3!$ (the number of partitions), but in the case with a restriction by $2!$. Why is the number of partitions with a given element excluded from the permutations of the partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing depends upon whether  group(s) are distinct or not. (Better terminology is to use "labeled/unlabeled").

In the first case, although it has not been explicitly mentioned, the division by $3!$ implies that the groups
are unlabeled.

In the second case, by stipulating that  *a certain element must belong to a given group*, that group becomes labeled. Since now only $2$ unlabeled groups are there, we divide by $2!$